# Prove that $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) < \frac{1}{({x^2 + x})^{1/2}}$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Prove that$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) < \frac{1}{({x^2 + x})^{1/2}}.$$
I assumed $$g(x) =  \frac{1}{({x^2 + x})^{1/2}} - \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and got it's derivative which is negative, which means, it is a decreasing function. But, it is a function where $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ never exceeds $\frac{1}{({x^2 + x})^{1/2}}$.[Graph for the function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s5msig4ttp) Also, $g(x)$ don't have any extremum points in $x > 0$. Both tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. How do I prove the inequality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes a bit simpler if you substitute $x = 1/u$. Then the inequality becomes
$$
 \log(1+u) < \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u}}
$$
which holds for $u > 0$ because
$$
 h(u) = \log(1+u) - \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u}}
$$
satisfies $h(0) = 0$ and $h$ is strictly decreasing:
$$
 h'(u) = \frac{2\sqrt{1+u} -(2+u)}{2(1+u)^{3/2}} < 0
$$
for $u > 0$ because $\sqrt{1+u} < 1 + \frac u2$.

Comment: While this is perhaps the "right" way to go about the problem, it is worth noting that the condition $h(u)=0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=0$, and if a function is decreasing and has a limit of $0$, it must always be positive.  The transformation $u=1/x$ converts the behavior as $x$ goes to infinity to the behavior as $u$ goes to $0$.This gives a solution to the problem that doesn't require any substitutions or algebraic tricks, as straight forward and reasonable and important as they might be.

Comment: Does $h'(x) < 0$ means decreasing function when we are approaching the axis from the right ? Shouldn't this be reversed too ? Because a person for who is approaching from right, concave curve means it is increasing, but if that person approaches it from left, it would mean decreasing.

Comment: @deathstroke: $h'(x) < 0$ means that the function is (strictly) decreasing, so that $h(x) < h(0)$ for $x > 0$. – (A function is *concave* if the *second* derivative is negative, or if the first derivative is decreasing. That is not used here.)

Comment: Sorry. I meant this. [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kdqhxxtl77). If you approach it from left, it is an decreasing function , if approach it from right, it is increasing, the way to measure slope angle should change.

Comment: @deathstroke: A function is called (strictly) decreasing if it is order-reversing, i.e. if $x < y$ implies $h(x) > h(y)$ (compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). For a differentiable function that is equivalent to the derivative being negative.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to show the inequality on $(0,\infty)$. It looks like you want to use the following theorem: Given two continuous functions $f , g \colon [a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ which are differentiable on $(a , \infty)$ such that $f(a) < g(a) $ and $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x \in (a,\infty)$ we have $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,\infty)$. 
It sounds like you already computed that $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ so we just need points $a_n \in \mathbb R$ with $a_n \to 0$ such that $f(a_n) < g(a_n)$. But for that we calculate $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac 1 n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \frac{1}{n^2}}} = \frac{n}{\sqrt 2} > \ln (1+n)$$for any $n \in \mathbb N$.